# Jquery submit select form when option is selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, forms

I have a select, with a long list, in which i can search it, with select2 jquery pluing.

my select:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectList", "Client", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "clientform", name = "clientoverviewform"}))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Select Client</label>
                @if (Model.ClientList != null)
                {
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="sel1" name="id">

                        @foreach (var client in Model.ClientList)
                        {
                            <option value="@client.Id">@client.Name</option>
                        }

                    </select>
                }
            </div><!-- end form-group-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Vis" class="form-control">
            </div><!-- end form-group-->
        }
```

I need it to be able to let me search and select the option i want to use. press enter or mouse click. and then it submits the form...

and offcourse it has to work with a normal submit button aswell...

i have tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clientform').on('change', function () {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form').on('change', function () { 
                $form.find('input[type=submit]').click();
            });
        });
    });
```

in which it submits before i even search, though it works if i just normally scrolls through the list and clicks..

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is, or what problem youre actually having. Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue (without us needing your server side code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to submit the form after you change the select option do:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: yes ofcourse... should have seen that... its only the select that changes..